# Fire third party API request when lead is updated in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I have created leads in the salesforce app using REST API. When I log in to the salesforce app, I am able to update/convert the lead. I want to send the updated lead object to a third-party API endpoint.

Is there any webhooks feature in Salesforce, like for a lead update I will subscribe to the webhook and give an endpoint address to call. Then the webhooks fires the URL with the updated lead data.

If yes, can somebody please explain to me the process of doing it?

Thank you,
Abhilash

Comment: Have a look at this post: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000MLSTIA4

Comment: Take a look at [salesforce.se] SE, there are a number of questions and answers on this topic over there.

Comment: @DavidBrossard Thank you for the document. I implemented a trigger and callout to send a request to my API. Can you please suggest to me, If the third party API endpoint isn't available / if an error is received as a response, How can I retry until the success response is received. The data sent from the trigger should be updated in my database so I want the Salesforce to retry if API request is failed.